# display an attr_accessor in html.erb view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to display some properties of a ruby class to my view. I get a undefined method age error when I try to do so.

person.rb

```
attr_accessor :age
```

controller action

```
def show
 @persons = Person.all
 @persons.each do |p|
   p.age = 25
 end
end
```

show.html.erb view

```
<%= @persons.each do |p| %>
   <%= p.age %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `show` is to display a single person, not a collection (`index` action is where you display the collection).

2) You should not have any troubles with displaying `age` once you have defined the `attr_accessor :age` in model.

So the following code is valid (even without assigning `age` to any of the `@persons`:

```
<%= @persons.each do |p| %>
  <%= p.age %>
<% end %>
```

Having that you showed

```
# person.rb
attr_accessor :seats
```

maybe you do not have neither

```
# person.rb
attr_accessor :age
```

nor the column called `age` in `people` (`persons`?) table.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, if Person is AR models, I advise you to use some gem like draper. 
It would create decorator for you model. And in decorator you can define default values, attr_accessors and it would be more elegant and practical solution.
And your code would look like:

```
def show
  @persons = Person.all.decorate
end
```